# How to get the hand/controller that pressed a button

Tags: mrtk

I would like to know, just by subscribing to the Interactable OnClick event, if I pressed the button with my left or right hand. Would that even be possible without passing this information along with the OnClick event?
The button has quite the logic to go through until it decides to accept a click request, so replicating all of that via global listener is not feasible.
Is it possible to get that information OnClick from somewhere else? Is it possible to query the potential click sources for who that was?

Answer (score 0):

Without altering the Interactable class the only way I found was to query the FocusProvider for the active pointer, which must have been the one pressing the button (in my case):
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Pointers.html

Answer (score 0):

https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/Controllers.html

Setup your controllers, take note of the axis name, in code you can do something like this in any GameObject's update loop:

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Axis1D.PrimaryHandButton") > 0.5f) {
// this axis (button) is pressed do something
}
```